# ViewController respondsToSelector: message sent to deallocated instance while buying consumable product

Tags: ios, swift2, in-app-purchase

I am having some trouble with buying products in test mode. I have 2 viewcontrollers. viewcontroller2 is IAP class. Buying coins works fine and its displays bought coins perfectly in label which is in viewcontroller1. So when I switch to viewcontroller1 (where I use coins) and go back to viewcontroller2 and hit buy button again to buy coins it crashes.

viewcontroller2:

```
import UIKit
import StoreKit

public var coins = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("coins")
public var ads = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("purchased")

class ViewController2: UIViewController, SKProductsRequestDelegate, SKPaymentTransactionObserver{

@IBOutlet var lblAd: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var lblCoinAmount: UILabel!

@IBOutlet var outRemoveAds: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var outAddCoins: UIButton!



// 1
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addTransactionObserver(self)




    outRemoveAds.enabled = false
    outAddCoins.enabled = false

    // Set IAPS
    if(SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments()) {
        print("IAP is enabled, loading")
        let productID:NSSet = NSSet(objects: "productId1", "productId2")
        let request: SKProductsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productID as! Set<String>)

        request.delegate = self
        request.start()
    } else {
        print("please enable IAPS")
    }

    lblCoinAmount.text = "\(coins)"

}



// 2
@IBAction func btnRemoveAds(sender: UIButton) {
    for product in list {
        let prodID = product.productIdentifier
        if(prodID == "productId1") {
            p = product
            buyProduct()
            break;
        }
    }

}

// 3
@IBAction func btnAddCoins(sender: UIButton) {
    for product in list {
        let prodID = product.productIdentifier
        if(prodID == "productId2") {
            p = product
            buyProduct()
            break;
        }
    }

}

// 4
func removeAds() {
    //lblAd.removeFromSuperview()
    let adsDefault = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    adsDefault.setBool(true , forKey: "purchased")
    adsDefault.synchronize()

}

// 5
func addCoins() {
    coins = coins + 50
    lblCoinAmount.text = "\(coins)"

    let CoinsDefault = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    CoinsDefault.setInteger(coins, forKey: "coins")

}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@IBAction func RestorePurchases(sender: UIButton) {
    //SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addTransactionObserver(self)
    SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().restoreCompletedTransactions()
}


var list = [SKProduct]()
var p = SKProduct()



func buyProduct() {
    print("buy " + p.productIdentifier)
    let pay = SKPayment(product: p)
    //SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addTransactionObserver(self)
    SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addPayment(pay)
}

func productsRequest(request: SKProductsRequest, didReceiveResponse response: SKProductsResponse) {
    print("product request")
    let myProduct = response.products

    for product in myProduct {
        print("product added")
        print(product.productIdentifier)
        print(product.localizedTitle)
        print(product.localizedDescription)
        print(product.price)

        list.append(product )
    }

    outRemoveAds.enabled = true
    outAddCoins.enabled = true
}

func paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished(queue: SKPaymentQueue) {
    print("transactions restored")

    for transaction in queue.transactions {
        let t: SKPaymentTransaction = transaction

        let prodID = t.payment.productIdentifier as String

        switch prodID {
        case "productId1":
            print("remove ads")
            removeAds()
        case "productId2":
            print("add coins to account")
            addCoins()
        default:
            print("IAP not setup")
        }

    }
}


func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
    print("add paymnet")

    for transaction:AnyObject in transactions {
        let trans = transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction
        print(trans.error)

        switch trans.transactionState {

        case .Purchased:
            print("buy, ok unlock iap here")
            print(p.productIdentifier)

            let prodID = p.productIdentifier as String


            switch prodID {
            case "productId1":
                print("remove ads")
                removeAds()
            case "productId2":
                print("add coins to account")
                addCoins()

            default:
                print("IAP not setup")
            }

            queue.finishTransaction(trans)
            break;
        case .Failed:
            print("buy error")
            queue.finishTransaction(trans)
            break;
        default:
            print("default")
            break;

        }
    }
}

func finishTransaction(trans:SKPaymentTransaction)
{
    print("finish trans")
    SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(trans)
}
func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue, removedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction])
{
    print("remove trans");
}




}
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing this line:

```
override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().removeTransactionObserver(self)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use following code in  **deinit** function in viewcontrollers

```
SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().removeTransactionObserver
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Instruments to investigate that error. 
Profile your application *(Cmd ⌘+I)* and then pick the template called Zombies.

Try to crash the app again. You should get more info about the "Zombie" object, and the stack state at that moment. 
If you don't manage to find out the cause, you can attach a screenshot of Instruments with the *Extended Details* pane open - I will try to help, if possible :)